# Modify magento sales email. (Card number)

Tags: php, magento

Currently in a Magento sales email, if the customer paid via credit card it only shows the last four digits of the card number. ex: xxxx-4532

How do I make it so it shows the first 4 and last 4? ex:4382-3827

This is for Magento 1.8.1.0

Comment: possibly related: [Changing the display of Credit Card information in Magento Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214271/changing-the-display-of-credit-card-information-in-magento-admin)

Comment: i would never do business with you if your sending such sensitive information via email

Comment: by default magento shows the last 4. I am looking to show the first 4 and last 4. Not the whole card number.

Comment: I belive the answer is somewhere in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/cc.phtml around line 100 however I do not know how to code it to make it show the first 4


        if ($this->getInfo()->getCcLast4()) {
            $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcLast4());

Comment: What credit card payment method are you, are you using the Magento  default 'save cc' in system -> config -> Payment?

Comment: last 4 is common, and i accept that, adding more is a security risk