# Card number in sales email first 4-last 4?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying make the first 4 and last 4 digits of the customers credit card number show in the sales email. Currently only the last 4 show in the sales email like so "`xxxx-6473`"

I am looking for  "`4553-3784`"

I believe the correct code for this is in `html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/cc.php` around line 100

```
if ($this->getInfo()->getCcLast4()) {
    $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcLast4());
```

I am on mangento 1.8.1.0

Comment: Repeated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024998/modify-magento-sales-email-card-number

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do this.  Magento doesn't save credit card numbers in the local database, it only saves the last four digits.  If you **are** saving credit card numbers to the database with the SavedCC method, you're probably in violation of whatever implicit or explicit PCI agreements you've made.

Comment: supporting to this answer, I dont think that your customer allows you to display the first 4 digits in the email or any other. I havent seen any where like displaying the first 4 digits also.. and also what is the use of displaying the first 4 digits???